# batch script to identify folders and zip & move them

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, php-ziparchive

I am a total newbie at windows scripting having spent over 13 yrs scripting in Unix shell. I need help in finding a way to find a folder last modified about 30 days back and then zip the folder and move it to another "Archive" folder. Folder structure is like the following :

```
D:\AuditFiles\2013.05
D:\AuditFiles\2013.06
D:\AuditFiles\Archive
```

So aim is to move `2013.05` into Archive directory after zipping it up.
I've tried forfiles.exe which doesnt allow me to skip the folder Archive and I've tried dir /ad but that doesnt allow me to specific last modified days been +30.

Comment: Maybe u need `for /r`

Comment: If you don't want to use PowerShell, VBScript, or some real programming language (Perl, Python, etc.), I'd use GNU find ([UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)). It's way better at this than any native Windows feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to install any utils. I need to script this up so that it can be used as a scheduled job to run on the first of every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one method to get the oldest folder, excluding Archive, which seems to be what you need.

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\AuditFiles\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /o-d') do (
if /i not "%%a"=="Archive" set "folder=%%a"
)
echo oldest folder is "%folder%"
popd
```

Comment: I've tried the above segment and I get

`
'"set folder=2013.06"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


'"set folder=2013.05"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


oldest folder is ""
`

Comment: @user2538606 try `set "folder=%%a"`. small typo.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way, assuming your date format is `Mo 07/01/2013`, check this with the command `echo %date%`:

```
@echo OFF &setlocal
REM %date% format is "Mo 07/01/2013"
FOR /f "tokens=2,4delims=/ "  %%a IN ("%date%") DO SET /a month=%%a, year=%%b
IF %month% equ 1 (
    SET /a month=12
    SET /a year-=1
) ELSE SET /a month-=1
if %month% lss 10 SET "month=0%month%"
SET "folderToSearch=%year%.%month%"
IF NOT EXIST "D:\AuditFiles\%folderToSearch%\" ECHO Folder NOT found: %folderToSearch%&goto:eof
ZIP [put options for your ZIP app here] "D:\AuditFiles\Archive\%folderToSearch%.zip" "D:\AuditFiles\%folderToSearch%"
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to address condition of the oldest directory other than Archive. If this script segment can incorporate the oldest directory bit then that would be great.

Comment: so take @foxidrive's solution. this `oldest directory other than Archive` is too confusing for me at the start of the week :)